# Union ALL with partition

Tags: sql, sql-server, union, window-functions

I have two separate queries and i want to combine them into one. on their own they are working fine, I tried using union but i can't seem to get it right. Basically one query is getting balance as of a certain date and the other is calculating activity for a range of dates. I want the results to appear into columns next to each other.

Tried writing query without partition and as a simple group by. used union but then i can't get the columns for the second query to appear on the main select statement.

```
Declare @Date datetime = '04/01/2019'
```

Code for beginning balance:

```
    Select Left(Account,4)Entity, right(Account,9)Account, sum(debit+credit)BBal
From GLT_CURRENT__TRANSACTION 
Where Left(Account,4) = '9452'  and 
Right(Account,9) IN ('1110.0130','1110.0131','2110.0061','2110.0062') 
and Accounting_Date <= EOMONTH('04-01-2019',-1)
Group By Left(Account,4), right(Account,9)
```

Code for sum of activity

```
    Select Left(Account,4)Entity,Right(Account,9),Sum(debit+credit)Activity
From GLT_CURRENT__TRANSACTION AS A Where 
Left(Account,4) = '9452' and Accounting_Date >= '04-01-2019' and Accounting_Date <= Eomonth('04-01-2019')
AND Right(Account,9) IN ('1110.0130','1110.0131','2110.0061','2110.0062')
Group By Left(Account,4), Right(Account,9)
```

How to combine the two on 1 row? Tried union but didn't work on the second query.

```
Entity   Account  BBalance Activity
  9452 1110.0130     50.00    2,500
```

Comment: If your union all query is producing one row of 4 columns output then one of the queries is returning no results. When you say "next to each other" do you mean you want one row of 8 columns output?

Comment: "Balance as of a certain date" sounds like you want to sum all rows back to beginning of time, from that date. "Activity between a range of dates" doesn't sound like a grouping query, sounds like multiple rows. These two concepts sound slightly disjointed to each other from an accounting perspective unless the "sum where less than date" is one of the activity range dates (eg It's a balance brought forward). Are you preparing an account statement with a "balance brought forward" at the top, which is the sum of all that came before, and then a detail line of every activity since then?

Comment: I agree about disjointed and if nothing else you need to explain which date condition to use for a merged query.

Comment: @CaiusJard  so the back ground is that i am trying to get a balance of 4 accounts as of certain date and right next to it i want to get the sum of transactions for the following month. total output should be 4 columns > Company, Account, Beginning balance, activity for next month. As you put it, yes a balance forward on a statement and then activity for the period after. But not detailed...i want the balance for the month.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson for example if the month is April then i need to get balance as at March 31st and the sum of activity(transactions) for the entire month of April. Imagine a statement of account that has your beginning balance and current month balance.  I wanted to run the query based on 1 parameter date i.e. your account balance as of 4/30/2019.

Comment: code to get beginning balance:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're over-complicating things

```
SELECT
    LEFT(Account,4) as Entity, 
    RIGHT(Account,9) as Account, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN accounting_date <= EOMONTH(@date, -1) THEN debit+credit END) as BBal,
    SUM(CASE WHEN accounting_date > EOMONTH(@date, -1) THEN debit+credit END) as Activity
FROM
    GLT_CURRENT__TRANSACTION 
WHERE
    Left(Account,4) = '9452'  and 
    Right(Account,9) IN ('1110.0130','1110.0131','2110.0061','2110.0062')  and
    Accounting_Date <= EOMONTH(@Date) 
GROUP BY 
    Left(Account,4), 
    right(Account,9)
```

This query, when given an @date like 14-Mar-2018, selects all transactions before the 31-Mar-2018. For each row, the CASE WHEN inside the SUM tests whether the accounting date is in the past (for bbal) or current month (for activity). If the accounting date for a particular transaction does not comply with the rule CASE WHEN test returns false) then the return value from the CASE WHEN is null, so it is not summed

To understand more about how this query works, run it without the grouping/summing:

```
SELECT
    LEFT(Account,4) as Entity, 
    RIGHT(Account,9) as Account, 
    Accounting_date,
    (CASE WHEN accounting_date <= EOMONTH(@date, -1) THEN debit+credit END) as BBal,
    (CASE WHEN accounting_date > EOMONTH(@date, -1) THEN debit+credit END) as Activity
FROM
    GLT_CURRENT__TRANSACTION 
WHERE
    Left(Account,4) = '9452'  and 
    Right(Account,9) IN ('1110.0130','1110.0131','2110.0061','2110.0062')  and
    Accounting_Date <= EOMONTH(@Date)
```

Transactions would be like this for @date in march:

```
1, 1, 02-Feb-18, $100, null --previous month
1, 1, 28-Feb-18, $300, null --previous month
1, 1, 02-Mar-18, null, $400 --current month
1, 1, 28-Mar-18, null, $500 --current month
```

See how the case when has split the transaction amount into either the bbal or activity column depending on the accounting date? Now when we sum those and group them (remove the date column from the query results):

```
1, 1, $400, $900  --the $400 is £100+$300, the $900 is $400+$500
```

Comment: I am still learning how to use the case statement. so versatile and solid. Thanks for the thorough explanation! your code is so simple and beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

Another easy way to do this would be using a CTE. The code is based off your beginning balance and movement queries above.

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME = '04/01/2019' --Set the variable for the first day of the period.

;with BeginningBalance
as
( 
    --Gather the beginning or opening balance
    Select 
        Left(Account,4) as Entity, 
        right(Account,9) as Account, 
        sum(debit+credit) as BBal
    From 
        GLT_CURRENT__TRANSACTION 
    Where 
        Left(Account,4) = '9452'  and 
        Right(Account,9) IN ('1110.0130','1110.0131','2110.0061','2110.0062')  and
        Accounting_Date <= EOMONTH(@Date,-1) --All transaction movement up until 31Mar
    Group By 
        Left(Account,4), 
        right(Account,9)
),
Activity --Activity / movement
as
(
    Select 
        Left(Account,4) as Entity,
        Right(Account,9) as Account,
        Sum(debit+credit)Activity
    From 
        GLT_CURRENT__TRANSACTION  
    Where 
        Left(Account,4) = '9452' and 
        Accounting_Date >= @Date and 
        Accounting_Date <= Eomonth(@Date) AND 
        Right(Account,9) IN ('1110.0130','1110.0131','2110.0061','2110.0062')
    Group By 
        Left(Account,4), 
        Right(Account,9)
)
SELECT 
    ISNULL(a.Entity, b.Entity) as [Entity], --Use entity from Beginning or activity just in case the account was made on or after 1APR or not used after 31Mar
    ISNULL(a.Account, b.Account) as [Account], --Use Account from Beginning or activity just in case the account was made on or after 1APR or not used after 31Mar
    ISNULL(BBal,0) as [BBal], --Zero opening if there is no opening balance
    ISNULL(Activity,0) as [Activity] --Zero activity if there is no account movement within the period
FROM 
    BeginningBalance a
FULL OUTER JOIN --Should include all rows from beginning balance & activity. You may want to exclude inactive accounts with zero balances as you're summing up values since the start of your GL
    Activity b
ON 
    a.Entity = b.Entity AND
    a.Account = b.Account
```

Comment: This one worked as well but its takes longer to process...the cost was 67% vs 33%. I am assuming its due to the join.

Thank you though! appreciate you spending the time to help out a total stranger!

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME = '04/01/2019'

SELECT  
A.Entity, 
A.Account,
SUM(A.BBalance) BBalance,
SUM(A.Activity) Activity
FROM
(
    SELECT LEFT(Account,4)Entity, 
    RIGHT(Account,9)Account,
    CAST(SUM(debit+Credit) OVER ( PARTITION BY Right(Account,9)) AS NUMERIC(8,2)) As BBalance,
    0 Activity
    FROM GLT_CURRENT__TRANSACTION 
    WHERE LEFT(Account,4) = '9452'  
    AND RIGHT(Account,9) IN ('1110.0130','1110.0131','2110.0061','2110.0062') 
    AND Accounting_Date <= EOMONTH(@Date,-1) As D
    GROUP BY Entity, D.Account, BBalance
    --ORDER BY Account

    UNION ALL

    SELECT LEFT(Account,4)Entity,
    RIGHT(Account,9),
    0 BBalance,
    SUM(debit+credit)Activity
    FROM GLT_CURRENT__TRANSACTION 
    WHERE LEFT(Account,4) = '9452' 
    AND Accounting_Date >= @Date 
    AND Accounting_Date <= Eomonth(@Date)
    AND RIGHT(Account,9) IN ('1110.0130','1110.0131','2110.0061','2110.0062')
    Group By LEFT(Account,4), RIGHT(Account,9)
)A
GROUP BY A.Entity,A.Account
```

Comment: This didn't work. UNION is red lined and also the last bracket preceding A.

Comment: Error? Or Unexpected output?

Comment: I'd suggest the following: 

1. Remove the order by & 2. You've got an extra closing bracket `EOMONTH(@Date,-1))`

Comment: Thanks @Matt. Both changes are applied. ORDER BY was unnecessary there and extra bracket was a Syntax issue.

Comment: @mkRabbani it was giving me error: incorrect syntax near ')'